# iOS 6 EmitterCells birthrate not working correctly

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I've found some more very strange behavior with regards to the CAEmitterCell in iOS 6.  ***Please note that these problems only exist when running iOS 6.  And also note that I'm referring too Cells that are children of other cells.***  I've tested iOS 6 vs iOS 7 on both devices and Simulators.

- In my extremely simple project linked below, if I have less than 70 objects (birthRate < 70) No Objects are created at all!  So if you set it to 50, you would expect 50 to be created... but non are created
- BirthRate for sub-Cells that spawn from other CAEmitterCells is not accurate.  When I set it to 70, it creates roughly 7...
- BeginTime is functioning very odd.  Let's say my parent cell has a LifeTime of 1.6.  If I set It's child cell's beginTime to be 1.5 it works correctly.  But if I set the child cell's beginTime to 1.4 (which should also work correctly) no cells are spawned at all... Anything less than it's parent's LifeTime should work, correct??

[Here is a video demonstrating the problems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmCiiJgAh_Q)

[Here is a dropbox link to the Xamarin.iOS C# Project I used to demonstrate these bugs/problems:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yz4c149vacyuxa/Test_particleEmittorFireworks.zip)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: There's no solution unfortunately.  The particle emitter in iOS 6 is bugged and will not be fixed.  I resorted to only supporting iOS 7 and up for my app since it relied on the particle emitter to work correctly :-\